# main: Prelude.!!: index too large

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a program that will copy a file and allow us to rename it, like a cp command in unix.

```
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TI

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let source =  args !! 0
  let dest = args !! 1
  input <- TI.readFile source
  TI.writeFile dest input
```

I tried this and got main: Prelude.!!: index too large

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, this means that the index is too large, so that means that `getArgs` returns a list that contains less than two elements.

Using `(!!)` is however often not a good idea: there is no guarantee that the element exists, and it runs in *(k)* to obtain the *k*-th element. You can work with:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    (src:dst:_) -> do
      input <- TI.readFile source
      TI.writeFile dest input
    _ -> putStrLn "You should provide a source and destination"
```

Also loading the entire content in a string is not a good idea, since the file can be larger than all (available) memory, thus crashing the system. Often copying is done through two file handlers: one that reads the source file, and one that writes to the target file, with only a small amount of memory used. Some file systems can also make copying more effective. For example by using two references to the same file, and only effectively making a copy if one of the two files is modified.